# Displaying sub-data rows inside a row in SlickGrid Table

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've started using SlickGrid and have to implement a kind of functionality where I need to show sub-row inside a parent row of SlickGrid.

Here's the scenario

[image]

Here's Asia, Europe is having sub categories in Services Column and these service columns are expandable/collapsible

I'm trying to customize [this](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html) for first column.

Is any other link/source available to refer to accomplish the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the grouping/aggregates example ?
http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

This offers very similar behaviour, but the exact 'cell-merging' behaviour you show is not currently available in SlickGrid. Slickgrid tends to use tree structures rather than a flat structure. That said, it may not be too hard to hack up, but it seems everyone wants a different visual layout and it becomes very hard to support them all.

If you don't need editing or scrolling, I'd suggest this would work best as an HTML table, or even a PDF.